# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers

Can someone help and explain why the code builds but breaks and sends out the error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)?

```
void biggest(int value1, int value2, int * resultPtr)
{
    if( value1 > value2 )
    {
        *resultPtr = value1;
    }
    else
    {
        *resultPtr = value2;     //the code breaks on this line
    }
}

int main()
{
    int* p;
    biggest(15, 20, p);
    cout << "The biggest value is " << *p << endl;
    return( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p is null and you try to write to it inside biggest.

You probably want:

```
int main()
{
    int p;
    biggest(15, 20, &p);
    cout << "The biggest value is " << p << endl;
    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: p is not guaranteed to be null.

Comment: its not guaranteed to be null as it is uninitialised but in this instance it is null as it says so in the error message.